Ubuntu SSH x11 forwarding, local terminal works but vscode integrated terminal cannot work
I encountered a problem when I am trying to show GUI in my local machine when connecting to remote through SSH. Here is the option of my local ~/.ssh/config file:
ForwardX11 Yes
ForwardX11Trusted Yes
ForwardAgent Yes

, and I enabled X11Forwarding yes in the remote /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
Strangely, I tried to run xeyes and some other GUI applications (e.g. an executive built from a source I downloaded from GitHub) and they worked well when I used my local system terminal directly but cannot work when I used the integrated terminal of VS Code. For example, I get the following error message when trying to run xeyes :
Error: Can't open display: localhost:12.0

, and this error message when trying to run another GUI application:
X11: Failed to open display localhost:12.0The GLFW library is not initializedThe GLFW library is not initializedThe GLFW library is not initializedSegmentation fault (core dumped)

Therefore, I thought there probably be some problems in my configuration of VS Code.
I haved searched the web. However, all the solutions seem not working for me, and all questions about VS Code I found are either on a local machine with Windows OS, which is different from mine, or not reciving the same error message. I tried to install extension of X11 in VS Code on both local and remote side, but it still didn't work.
The OS of my local and the remote machines are both Ubuntu 20.
Does anyone know what's the problem? Thanks a lot!
